# FB Comment Box - Need to change text color

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I need to change the default text color of the FB Comment box.  Both settings "light" and "dark" provide only black text.

Is there a workaround or a way to change the text color to white?

.fbFeedbackPost .postText

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that, the widget is hosted in an iframe and you have no influence on it beside the documented parameters.